# Рандомная генерация квадратов в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть функция, которая генерирует квадрат рандомного размера не больше 40px в рандомном месте, не выходя за границы `canvas`:
1. Как сделать минимальный размер квадрата? Рандомно от 20 до 40.
2. При генерации 20 квадратов как сделать, чтобы они не появлялись друг в друге? Желательно с минимальным отступом.

```
function drawSquare(canvas, context){
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var w = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);

  context.fillStyle = "lightblue";
  context.fillRect(x,y,w,w);
}

for (var squares = 0; squares < 20; squares++) {
      drawSquare(canvas, context);
}
```

Comment: `var w = 20 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);` Очевидно же, что запоминать уже сгенеренные квадраты и проверять на пересечения.

Comment: @Igor можно пример?

Comment: Пример чего? Попробуйте сначала сами: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp.